# Is this a valid PHP array access method?

Tags: php, arrays

This is just a question of curiosity...
I'm wondering if accessing function returned arrays in this method is valid. In this example, I'm using the pathinfo() resulting array.

```
pathinfo($file)['dirname'];
```

Or, is it required to set pathinfo() to a variable first and then access it. (The classic method):

```
$info = pathinfo($file);
$info['dirname'];
```

I know the classic method is valid, however i'm just curious if the first method is valid too. I've tested it with the latest version of WAMP, and it worked, however Dreamweaver CS5 calls it a syntax error.

Comment: They're both _valid_ (meaning they will work) in PHP 5.4. In PHP < 5.4, only the second is valid. However, neither is acceptable, since you're not using quotes around your array key like you should. PHP is just (sadly) lenient enough to convert that to a string for you (IF the constant doesn't exist)

Comment: I forgot the quotes, i've edited to fix.

Answer (score 1):

PHP 5.4+ supports `pathinfo($file)['dirname'];`

It is called as array dereferencing

Ref: http://www.schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

and less than 5.4

```
$info = pathinfo($file);
$info['dirname'];
```

Comment: @ColinMorelli I edited his answer and added quotes, however it may theoretically be that there was `define('dirname', 5)` or similar earlier in the code, in which case the quotes should not be added.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was hoping it would be an earlier version, because my production server is 5.3.1.

Comment: @AleksG And, given the code sample above, that would be an invalid assumption to make. Because the likelihood is that there's not. Besides, it doesn't hurt to add them _and indicate why_ (that way you leave the decision up to the asker).

Comment: @Johnno13 : then you need to use second mehtod

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP 5.4 it's possible to do exactly that:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-88